Understanding difference in significance tests between non-spatial and spatial linear models
I have a dataset that demonstrates spatial correlation. When I test models without accounting for spatial correlation, one of the predictors is not significant, but when I use the fitme() function from the R package spaMM, the results are indicated as significant. Here is the code to create the dataset.
ID = c("CF1_1", "CF1_2", "CF1_3", "CF1_4", "CF2_1", "CF2_2", "CF2_3", 
       "DT1_1", "DT2_1", "DT3_1", "FL1_1", "FL1_2", "FL1_3", "FL1_4", 
       "FL2_1", "FL2_2", "FL2_3", "FL2_4", "HL1_1", "HL2_1", "HL3_1", 
       "JR1_1", "JR2_1", "JR3_1", "CA-1", "CA-2", "CA-3", "CM-1", "CM-2", 
       "CM-3", "CM-4", "LM-1", "LM-2", "LM-3", "LG-1", "LG-2", "LG-3", 
       "MD-1", "MD-2", "MD-3", "NN-1", "NN-2", "NN-3", "RR-1", "RR-2", 
       "RR-3", "SM-1", "WC-1", "WC-2", "WC-3", "VSN177041", "VSN177125", 
       "VSN796206", "VSN796043", "VSN796068", "VSN796081", "VSN796085", 
       "VSN796098", "VSN796110", "VSN796130", "VSN796138", "VSN796142", 
       "VSN796213", "VSN796145")
y = c(-1.4771773000026, -1.47717911000174, -1.47717430000141, -1.47718684799915, 
      -1.47729339999752, -1.47729452000163, -1.47730120499876, -1.45523699999726, 
      -1.45498899999879, -1.45558499999842, -1.47678865999622, -1.47678714999769, 
      -1.47678192000123, -1.47679539000003, -1.47685169999811, -1.47684866999867, 
      -1.47684613000082, -1.47685904899928, -1.47038599999956, -1.47042699999951, 
      -1.47043099999703, -1.46530800000158, -1.46533100000025, -1.46533499999806, 
      -1.49143811000205, -1.49137638999942, -1.49146008000285, -1.45834274000296, 
      -1.45827666000152, -1.45824127999855, -1.45833086000295, -1.46098506000058, 
      -1.4609076000037, -1.46078049999551, -1.48601250999756, -1.4859609199972, 
      -1.4856218799981, -1.48332980000049, -1.48360970999965, -1.48361907999938, 
      -1.49266048999847, -1.49273228999755, -1.49240795000034, -1.45719177999907, 
      -1.45722138000292, -1.45727202999797, -1.45967135999784, -1.46925018000211, 
      -1.46923487000083, -1.46923873000269, -0.906562422871527, -0.906753639231772, 
      -0.89818424364742, -0.899019165053894, -0.89582554042087, -0.899849917825566, 
      -0.898024723922124, -0.897300860810925, -0.897151095729909, -0.898011224422881, 
      -0.898217837101006, -0.899609074910954, -0.898280769148554, -0.885310228932147
)

x = c(1.29754371980031, 1.2975364391978, 1.29753198000274, 1.29753633200159, 
      1.29761920040404, 1.29761464080034, 1.29761219999965, 1.27804540000503, 
      1.27892899999832, 1.27805539999891, 1.29747185999651, 1.29747827999781, 
      1.29746842000226, 1.29746871999193, 1.29744836059685, 1.29745470060409, 
      1.29744312019674, 1.29744714339706, 1.29522660000691, 1.29522560000127, 
      1.29522359999132, 1.29263039999498, 1.29259739999907, 1.29262060000848, 
      1.28652930059613, 1.28653650060307, 1.28656062040319, 1.27429933940002, 
      1.27428149939885, 1.27431652059865, 1.27434677919824, 1.26148102059678, 
      1.26149370079602, 1.26124473980418, 1.31021166060422, 1.31021005959677, 
      1.31033263980021, 1.29900932060314, 1.29889158019649, 1.29886922059468, 
      1.29145508019729, 1.29154284040205, 1.2912357592021, 1.26688907980207, 
      1.26704571919054, 1.26701316060327, 1.26097635960324, 1.29104292020345, 
      1.29114113939416, 1.29098204079479, 0.981465625382686, 0.970411126166036, 
      0.96932294345795, 0.962439513370268, 0.972982392102993, 0.962072334156217, 
      0.960955451172507, 0.972500460183664, 0.960597917424426, 0.96095251077338, 
      0.963206366280823, 0.962095674045259, 0.963347233613211, 0.979914611817726
)

Y_value = c(43.61302521, 41.21428571, 42.55, 44.05, 33.02142857, 31.86428571, 
            28.7, 25.6, 38.08, 49.4, 22.4, 31.9, 27.53571429, 35.5, 58.86428571, 
            43.31428571, 56.55, 43.86428571, 15.52, 28.86, 39.55, 19.35, 
            19.4, 20.25, 27.7, 51.15, 15, 38.3, 34.85, 25.9, 18.6, 20.05, 
            19.25, 14.65, 24.3, 34.2, 16.5, 27.5, 26.4, 38.45, 21.9, 23.05, 
            28.7, 23.8, 9.9, 14.65, 25.9, 37, 21.25, 45.7, 38.92, 36.5, 46.84, 
            87.39, 39.13, 46.89, 173.43, 152.84, 152.26, 170.26, 74.62, 57.84, 
            31.11, 44.45)

X_value = c(4654.07370175, 4705.24971278, 3831.89807129, 4205.83492025, 
            2900.24372415, 2874.32917132, 3734.87277401, 2735.90609741, 2954.04777976, 
            4943.36721622, 2413.13208008, 2944.266619, 2503.79114488, 2348.43567613, 
            5074.2465549, 4971.23310547, 4907.59395106, 4654.29498291, 2701.70559692, 
            5317.65722656, 4661.51028442, 4569.98165894, 4314.39376831, 4136.65110869, 
            2828.96150716, 3961.24311523, 2693.94232537, 5806.2053833, 4826.55605469, 
            5503.06879021, 5829.38931274, 5755.57212612, 4670.91090495, 4882.85687615, 
            3800.5480957, 4730.71663411, 5478.83648682, 4854.11308019, 4916.41750919, 
            4396.23032514, 4574.65174058, 5040.67037964, 4717.49430339, 5389.74583333, 
            3073.03594612, 7438.87719727, 5237.27319336, 5093.24988511, 2870.37852478, 
            5529.99977022, 3045.12280273, 4508.4321733, 4917.25048828, 4597.8178267, 
            4449.5530229, 4439.78548177, 5161.51491477, 5360.71058239, 4319.69501953, 
            5918.30135831, 5627.73299893, 5693.52600098, 4989.37744141, 5414.90635851
)


class = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
                    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                    2L, 4L, 3L), levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")
  
dat = data.frame(ID,x,y,Y_value,X_value,class)

and here is the code to produce graphs and test hypotheses.
figure.gg = ggplot(dat,aes(X_value,Y_value, color = class)) +
  geom_point(data = dat,aes(X_value,Y_value)) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula= y~x) +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("Y") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 16)) 

print(figure.gg)

# model comparison
model_full.lm = lm(Y_value ~ X_value * class,data=dat)
model1.lm = lm(Y_value ~ X_value  +  class,data=dat)
model2.lm = lm(Y_value ~ class ,data=dat)
model3.lm= lm(Y_value ~ 1,data=dat)

car::Anova(model1.lm,model2.lm)

dists <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(dat$x, dat$y)))

dists.inv <- 1/dists
diag(dists.inv) <- 0

Moran.I(dat$X_value, dists.inv) ### spatial correlation

# spatial model
model.fitme = fitme(Y_value ~ X_value + class + Matern(1 | x + y), data = dat)
summary(model.fitme)

model1.fitme  = fitme(Y_value ~ class + Matern(1 | x + y), data = dat)

LRT(model.fitme,model1.fitme)  
```

Basically, I don't understand why car::Anova(model1.lm,model2.lm) yields Y_value as not significant but LRT(model.fitme,model1.fitme)  indicates that Y_value is significant. Any assistance as to what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

The following toy example illustrates an explanation for cases where a fixed effect appears non-significant when tested in a linear model, but appears significant when tested in a spatial linear mixed-effect model:
library("spaMM")
geo <- seq(100)/5
x <- rep(seq(2),50)
set.seed(123)
y <- geo + x + rnorm(100)
toydata <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,geo=geo)

yis defined so that there is an effect of x, but there is also a large effect geo of a spatial trend, which translates into a large estimate of residual variance in the non-spatial fit, full.lm below. The test of the effect of x by comparison of linear models is not significant:
full.lm <- lm(y~x, data=toydata)
anova(full.lm) # p=0.3341

But if the spatial trend is represented by the spatially autocorrelated random effect, the fitted residual variance is much lower and the effect becomes significant:
full.lmm <- fitme(y~x+Matern(1|geo), data=toydata)
null.lmm <- fitme(y~1+Matern(1|geo), data=toydata)
anova(full.lmm,null.lmm) # p < 1e-6 by generic likelihood-ratio test
anova(full.lmm, test="F") # calling lmerTest::anova(): p < 1e-6 

To obtain such a contrast between the tests, it is important that x varies at a smaller spatial scale than the geographical trend. Otherwise, the test based on the linear model may be confounded by the spatial effect, and may give a highly significant p-value for x even if x as no effect. By contrast, here, the non-significant p-value from the linear model is part of the pattern to be explained.

The first remark for this kind of question is always that the two tests test different hypotheses, so one shouldn't necessarily expect them to give the same result.
Looking at the data, it seems that the leverage point at X_value$>$7000 (observation 46) drags the X_value slope down in model1.lm, resulting in an insignificant X_value slope that comes from aggregating information in all data, whereas looking at the individual groups, we see positive slopes in the groups A, B, D, but C is by far the biggest group, including the leverage point, and drags the overall slope down. A leverage point is an observation outlying in X-space that often has strong influence on the regression slope. Removing observation 46, the leverage outlier, X_value will be highly significant also in lm (removing outliers is not generally recommended, but it is instructive to see the influence that it has). A model with different slopes in different groups could make sense, but given the low numbers of observations in groups A, B, D, I'm not sure results will be satisfactory.
The fitme models bring in the geographical information. Looking at (x,y), there are two strongly separated and very homogeneous groups of locations. If I understand the models correctly, the models will imply a strong correlation between any two observations belonging to the same group of locations, i.e., similar values of Y_value within each class, as long as X_value is not involved. The significant result for X_value probably comes from the fact that within the same class and the same group of locations, higher Y_value can be explained by higher X_value. Particularly the low Y_value of the observation with X_value>7000 can now be explained largely by spatial correlation, and as a consequence, X_value can now be significant, because the influence of the leverage point on the X_value-slope is now lower. Chances are that this is better than the plain lm models.
